# XNA crop 2d Texture

Tags: c#, xna, textures

Hey guys, is there a way to crop a 2d texture?
Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the source rectangle of the texture smaller and it will be cropped.

Comment: I was researching this some more, and that looks like the only way to do it :(.  I was looking to add that to an accessor..  
Oh well, thanks!